# "Аргументы имеют невернный тип" - (Delphi + MySQL). Почему?

Tags: mysql, delphi, adoconnection

Ситуация следующая.
Пытаюсь создать запрос к БД (БД на MySQL) на добавление записи.
Пошёл следующим путём, через параметры:

```
      Form1.ADOQuery1.SQL.Add('INSERT INTO exam_users (`family`, `name`, `patronymic`, `birthdate`) VALUES  (:family, :name, :patronymic, :birthdate)');

      Form1.ADOQuery1.Parameters.ParamByName('family').Value:= Edit1.text;
      Form1.ADOQuery1.Parameters.ParamByName('name').Value:= Edit2.text;
      Form1.ADOQuery1.Parameters.ParamByName('patronymic').Value:= Edit3.text;
      Form1.ADOQuery1.Parameters.ParamByName('birthdate').Value:= Edit4.text;

      Form1.ADOQuery1.ExecSQL;
```

Т.е. в запрос пошли текстовые переменные.
Их запись в БД происходит, но с предупредительным окном (Exception - см.картинку). В БД поля тоже текстовые: `text`.
Чем вызвано такое поведение Delphi, или, точнее даже драйвера MySQL? (Так как подключаюсь через "mysql-connector-odbc-5.2.7")?
(рис.1, рис.2).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: В какой строке кода возникает ошибка? Что видно в логе MySQL? Возможно у вас проблемы с кодировкой.

Comment: @kot-da-vinci, ошибка возникает в строке `Form1.ADOQuery1.SQL.Add('...`. Delphi ведь работает из-под OS Windows, по всем правилам должна и в кодировке cp1251 подавать данные в таблицу. Так как данные ведь приходят и в нормальном, читабельном виде (в кириллице) .

Comment: нет таких правил.

Answer (score 2):

До выполнения кода `Form1.ADOQuery1.SQL.Add` что происходит с `Form1.ADOQuery1`?

Возможно там уже есть sql скрипт и вы пытаетесь добавить еще один.

Попробуйте очистить `Form1.ADOQuery1.SQL.Clear;`. А лучше использовать `Form1.ADOQuery1.SQL.Text := 'sql script';` - в таком случае конфликтов не должно быть.

**UPD1**

Мы тут гадаем, а на самом деле все просто. [`TEXT`](http://www.mysql.ru/docs/man/Column_types.html) - 
Столбец типа `BLOB` или `TEXT` с максимальной длиной 65535 (2^16 - 1) символов.

C `BLOB` полями работа ведется немного по другому. В таких полях в основном лежат большие объекты. Работа с `Blob` полем можно посмотреть к примеру  [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26103437/2546083).

У Вас есть 2 путя:

- Изменить тип поля на [`Varchar`](http://www.mysql.ru/docs/man/CHAR.html)
- Научить программу работать с blob полями.

Я больше склонен к первому пункту поскольку на имя, фамилию.... нужно не более 255 символов.

Comment: перед `add` происходит стандартное `Form1.ADOQuery1.Close; Form1.ADOQuery1.SQL.Clear;`
Пробовал менять на `ADOQuery1.Text:=`, результат всё тот же.

Comment: Можно попробовать посмотреть что же все таки приходит серверу MySQL. Обсуждение [тут](http://stackoverflow.com/a/568567/2546083)

Comment: *нужно не более 255 символов* - Заблуждения программистов насчет имен, пункт номер 6. https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/